# How to prevent special characters in datagridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview

I have a windows forms vb.net program that uses a datagridview. I'm trying to find a way to prevent a user from entering special characters (e.g. $,@,!,#,%,^,&) in my datagridview. When the user inputs a special character I have an approprioate message box appear explaining their mistake, then I provide them a default value. I have everything working except a way to prevent the special character or symbols. I'm thinking something like this has to work, but I can't seem to find any way of preventing this sort of entry:

```
 If (columnindex = 0) Then 'checking value for column 1 only
            Dim cellString = DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex).value
            If cellString String.IsSymbol(cellString) = true Then

                    MessageBox.Show("Special Characters Not Allowed")
                End If
                DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(columnindex).value = "Default Value"
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EditingControlShowing` event to register a `KeyPress` function for the input box.

```
Private Sub YourDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles YourDataGridView.EditingControlShowing

    Try
        RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf YourFunctionToPreventSpecialCharacters
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    If Me.dgvTableViewer.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = YourDataGridView.Columns("YourColumn").Index Then
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf YourFunctionToPreventSpecialCharacters
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the best way to attach a handler to the TextBox control inside the datagridview, but this implementation is problematic because you never remove the handler.  Each time you enter the control the handler gets added again (and will therefore fire as many times as you've added the handler - on the 10th entry to the cell the handler will fire ten times!!).  You need to keep a reference to `e.Control` and call `RemoveHandler` on that object, then do `AddHandler` and update your reference.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I remove this part of code (my error) to simplify the answer! I simply use a Try/Catch block to RemoveHandler instead of keep a reference to e.Control. Answer updated.

Comment: This works as well. You don't need the try/catch, however.  `RemoveHandler` will never throw an exception except if the argument is null.  `e.Control` may be null during construction/destruction so  `If e.Control IsNot Nothing Then...` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try and Put this in the DataGridView's keydown event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.D0 To Keys.D9 And e.Shift
            MsgBox("NOPE.")
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

That basically checks if the keypress is coming from the 0-9 keys on your computer and also if you are holding the `SHIFT` Key. If it is then it displays a Msgbox and Suppresses the keypress. This blocks chars on your keyboard's 0-9 shift `!@#$%^&*()`. You can edit this like

```
Case Keys.A
    e.Suppress ...
    Msgbox ... etc
```

Comment: You have access to the shift state via `e.Shift` - you should probably use this as it is possible that the message handler can fire after the user has released the shift key and `My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown` will report false even though the shift key *was* pressed when the event was fired.

Comment: All the above answers are based on the Key press event. What if the user has pasted the value?

Comment: also, this doesn't seem to work - the cell has focus when entering text, not the gridview.

Comment: Binding this method using tezzo's approach will work.  You must remove the `MsgBox` from the handler, however, since it is a modal dialog and will interfere with the message loop sequence (making `e.SuppressKeyPress` fail to suppress the key press).